# Create keystroke to a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

In Google "documents" (not Spreadsheets), I've a script to insert Date. How do I create a keystroke to activate the script?

Answer (score 1):

At this time Google Documents / Google Apps Script doesn't include a way to set a custom keyboard shortcut to run a script.

There is at least one feature request about this.

[Feature request: map shortcut to script functions in Google Docs](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79461369)